# SublimeText: How to find the command for "Next Build Result" to map it to a different key?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Background: I am working on an SML file on SublimeText3 with build system setup.

After a build, i can successfully jump to the first error using the `F4` key. I want to add another key mapping for the same "Next Result" command eg:`Cmd+N` in Vintage mode.

1. What should i add as in my keybindings file to achieve this?
2. What documentation,file did you refer/look around to find the proper answer for question 1? What was your thought process in brief to figure it out ?

edit: changed the required keybinding from `<leader>cn` to `Cmd+N` to make things easier

Comment: Could you please explain what `<leader>cn` means?.Maybe [this example](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/how-to-remap-escape-in-sublime-text-3s-vintage-mode) is useful for your problem.

Comment: i have already done that. How do i find what is the corresponding command for "Next Build Result" to add in a similar key binding?

Comment: its a common Vim usage where `,` or `backslash` is set as a `leader` and a lot of commands are mapped to key sequences starting with the `leader`. The `<leader>cn` i am looking for  is the key sequence `comma,c,n` but i am okay with a normal `Cmd+N` sequence for now.

Comment: Using menu `Preferences>KeyBindings-Default` you can see the default key bindings. If you find f4 you can see that the command being called is `next_result` . Is that?

Comment: Yes. Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the command being called on a default key-binding in the default key bingings file. This file is opened using the menu:

```
Preferences > Key Bindings - Default
```

Inside this file you must find the entry corresponding to the keys you are looking for, in this case `f4` key is mapped to **`next_result` command** as you can see in the key binding:

```
{ "keys": ["f4"], "command": "next_result" }
```

Comment: @saadq This is a completely different and valid way of doing it. You should post it as an answer. Also note that Mikhail can't be notified of your comment because he hasn't make any comment in my answer, I think you were trying to post it as a comment to the question.

Comment: Oops. Yeah, meant to post that as a comment to the question. And I didn't realize I couldn't notify him until he commented, thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're wlcome. I once come to this useful meta question [How do comment replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 6):

For future reference, you can type `sublime.log_commands(True)` into the Sublime console and then the command name of every action you do will get printed to the console. Once you get the command name you need, you can stop the command printing with `sublime.log_commands(False)`

Comment: Thank you. :) bot the answers are equally helpful.