# ST3 Can't write dot ["."] while "Java syntax" is on

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 and I can't (that means when I press the key nothing happens) `.` while I have active `java syntax`. When I switch to another syntax (f.e. `Javascript`) problem is gone. Do anyone solved had/solved this problem?

[Installed packages]

```
{
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "AngularJS",
        "Better JavaScript",
        "Display Functions (Java)",
        "DocBlockr",
        "EditorConfig",
        "Emmet",
        "Format SQL",
        "Git",
        "Goto Documentation",
        "Grunt",
        "HexViewer",
        "HTML Boilerplate",
        "HTML5",
        "JavaPropertiesEditor",
        "Javascript Beautify",
        "jQuery",
        "JsFormat",
        "LESS",
        "LineEndings",
        "MoveTab",
        "Nette",
        "Nunjucks Syntax",
        "Package Control",
        "PHP Namespace Command",
        "PHP-Twig",
        "Phpcs",
        "PhpDoc",
        "Quick File Move",
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "SJSON",
        "SublimeLinter",
        "SublimeLinter-csslint",
        "SublimeLinter-html-tidy",
        "SublimeLinter-jshint",
        "SublimeLinter-json",
        "SublimeLinter-php",
        "Theme - Phoenix",
        "VCS Gutter",
        "WordCount"
    ]
}
```

[User settings]

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/Monokai (SL).tmTheme",
    "default_line_endings": "unix",
    "detect_slow_plugins": false,
    "draw_white_space": "selection",
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "font_face": "Consolas",
    "font_size": 10,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "JavaScript",
        "Vintage",
        "tern_for_sublime"
    ],
    "show_encoding": true,
    "show_line_endings": true,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean when you say you can't write `.`? Does something happen when you press that key? Please describe your problem more clearly. Also, please list the plugins you are using. I cannot replicate your problem.

Comment: Also, it might help if you include your User preferences settings.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Java in Sublime 3 text: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yEq4_ap_XA

Comment: Have you tried disabling packages? You can disable all packages, if this solves your problem you can try disabling only some of them until you find the culprit (if any).

Comment: (I forgot to add the link in a previouse deleted comment) In addition you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31465400/3870761) to find out in console what command (if any) is being executed when you press `.` in a java syntax file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [sergioFC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3870761/sergiofc) comment I did `sublime.log_commands(True)` and it showed up that package `Display Functions (Java)` is "blocking" the `.` key. Disabling the package solved my problem.